# is there any tool to figure out the memory occupies by the swf?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flash

Well i am not asking about the tool to compress or measure the size of swf file , i need a tool that can show me how many bytes or mbs, my swf is using ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean a profiler, and yes there are a few options.

First I would recommend using [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) to er... develop your Flash software. It has a great profiler that can show you memory usage over time and also give you a live rundown one how much memory each object is using and how many of an object type exists (great for finding memory leaks).

There is also [De Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/). For a great video tutorial that covers the basics see [Lee Brimelow's - Debugging with MonsterDebugger](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=109).